# Schedule design - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a schedule for a gym and i m not sure how to structure it. A week looks something like this:

```
          mon           tue          wed          thu        sat    

6pm       class1       class1      class1      class1 

7pm       class1       class1      class2      class1

8pm       class2       class3      class1      class3

9pm       class1       class1                  class1
```

Saturdays have different schedules one week there's a seminar on nutrition while another week members can go to a class if they missed it during the week

```
10am                                                        class1

11am                                                        class2

1pm                                                         seminar
```

I want to use custom posts with custom fields to generate this. Members will have access to a page where they can view classes by month and join them.

If I create one individual custom post ... class and add custom fields like `date`, `start_time`, `end_time`, then when a user joins I can add a `member` custom field for each one, it will take a really long time to add the classes for a whole year. But it will provide a unique id for each class which will make it easier to switch trainers or take a user out and put another in.

Or I can create a class1 custom post with date custom fields like this: `2015-07-30 / 10:00:00 / 11:00:00` where the date, start time and end time are all in one custom field and then use explode to get the data into an array. Users will be added in a separate custom post and will be shown in classes based on date?

Those are the two options I've come up with ... anybody have any better suggestions or improvements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i also have a similar idea, why dont you instead use this plugin and make changes to it. 
http://codecanyon.net/item/timetable-responsive-schedule-for-wordpress/7010836

Or you can even take ideas on how they have done it by viewing the plugin images.

Comment: I don't want to use a plugin.

Comment: Ok then how about using classes as taxonomies.

Comment: OK ... i m reading a bit about taxonomies now. Can you explain what you have in mind please?

Comment: Well taxonomies are like custom categories but you can also you them as tags. So you can use classes as taxonomies on every custom post type. For instance if you have custom post type for every day of the week then you can add 4 classes to it in the order you want them. Using taxonomy tags have the advantage that you can use them in a particular order ie. first taxonomy will be class1 on 6pm, second taxonomy will be class2 on 7pm etc